# Create xml like example below and make a request

Tags: c#

I need to create an xml which it will look like xml below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
-<env:Envelope xmlns:ns3="http://rgwspublic2/RgWsPublic2" xmlns:ns2="http://rgwspublic2/RgWsPublic2Service" xmlns:ns1="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
-<env:Header>
-<ns1:Security>
-<ns1:UsernameToken>
<ns1:Username>xxxx</ns1:Username>
<ns1:Password>yyyy</ns1:Password>
</ns1:UsernameToken>
</ns1:Security>
</env:Header>
-<env:Body>
-<ns2:rgWsPublic2AfmMethod>
-<ns2:INPUT_REC>
<ns3:afm_called_by/>
<ns3:afm_called_for>xxxxxxxxx</ns3:afm_called_for>
</ns2:INPUT_REC>
</ns2:rgWsPublic2AfmMethod>
</env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

I am new in xmls. How can i create an xml like this?
Also if is it easier to create an xml from a list collection?

Then i try to make a request like example below

```
 HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
        var response = await httpClient.PostAsync("https://www1.gsis.gr:443", new StringContent(booksFromFile.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/xml"));
        var HttpResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        Console.WriteLine(HttpResponse);
```

But i am getting error

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<meta http-equiv="REFRESH" content="0;url=http://www.gsis.gr"></HEAD>
<BODY>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try xml linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>" +
                           "<env:Envelope" +
                              " xmlns:ns3=\"http://rgwspublic2/RgWsPublic2\"" +
                              " xmlns:ns2=\"http://rgwspublic2/RgWsPublic2Service\"" +
                              " xmlns:ns1=\"http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd\"" +
                              " xmlns:env=\"http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope\">" +
                            "</env:Envelope>";

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
            XElement root = doc.Root;
            XNamespace nsEnv = root.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("env");
            XNamespace ns1 = root.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("ns1");
            XNamespace ns2 = root.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("ns2");
            XNamespace ns3 = root.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("ns3");

            XElement header = new XElement(nsEnv + "Header", 
                    new XElement(ns1 + "Security",
                    new XElement(ns1 + "UsernameToken")));
            XElement usernameToken = header.Descendants(ns1 + "UsernameToken").FirstOrDefault();
            string username = "xxxxx";
            string password = "yyyy";

            usernameToken.Add(new XElement(ns1 + "Username", username));
            usernameToken.Add(new XElement(ns1 + "Password", password));

            root.Add(header);

            XElement body = new XElement(nsEnv + "Body",
                            new XElement(ns2 + "rgWsPublic2AfmMethod",
                            new XElement(ns2 + "INPUT_REC")));
            XElement inputRec = body.Descendants(ns2 + "INPUT_REC").FirstOrDefault();

            root.Add(body);

            string afmCalledFor = "xxxxxxxxx";
            inputRec.Add(new XElement(ns3 + "afm_called_by"));
            inputRec.Add(new XElement(ns3 + "afm_called_for", afmCalledFor));

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!! But i am still getting the same result.<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN"> I am sendign my xml as string. Why i getting this error?

Comment: Thank you Sir for answer, Sorry i can't understand what meta is.Now i am just getting error 415. Unsopported Media Type

Comment: Are you still getting error 415?  The 415 error is a proxy error indicating that port number 443 which uses TLS/SSL is not working properly.  The error 415 is a proxy error and probably due to an expired certificate or the encryption mode in your code is not the same as the certificate.  Or you are not finding the proxy server.